# how to configure CloudFront with ec2 instance and elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, elastic-ip

I have a blog(codeoverflow.in) hosted on `aws-ec2` instance. I am using `cloudfront` and `acm` certificate to provide ssl for my blog. But when I access codeoverflow.in or www.codeoverflow.in, cloudfront redirect me to https version successfully but gives the following error:

> The request could not be satisfied. CloudFront wasn't able to connect
>   to the origin.  Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
>   TE89T-COJiVFgBGUpBG_2gWd6Iim3c-svHsborUct49O9Owjb3nl6g==

I have type A  and type AAAA alias records for both codeoverflow.in and www.codeoverflow.in in route 53, all pointing to cloudfront distribution.custom ssl certificate is also configured for both domains.as of now I have dissociated elastic ip from ec2, but I want to use it as well together with cloudfront and ec2. Please help me to configure all three together.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to connect to your origin via HTTPS, but it doesn't sound like you have SSL enabled on your instance.

The easiest thing to do is use a hostname for your origin - i.e. www-origin.codeoverflow.in.  Create a load balancer that listens on both 80 & 443, deploy an appropriate cert to that (you may have to create a new one, or create a wildcard) and put your instance behind that listening on port 80.  Finally, create an ALIAS record in Rour53 from www-origin to your load balancer.

Comment: Good advice.  This error would also occur if you had a self-signed or otherwise untrusted cert on the origin, [or even a missing certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38841070/1695906).      Sometimes "unable to connect" technically means "unwilling to  connect" due to certificate trust issues.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Are you sure that's true?  I know an ELB will connect to an EC2 instance using SSL with a self-signed cert - it does not do cert validation.  I haven't actually tested putting EC2 directly behind Cloudfront however.

Comment: Yes, CloudFront is very strict with SSL validation of the origin. *"Caution: If the origin server returns an expired certificate, an invalid certificate or a self-signed certificate, or if the origin server returns the certificate chain in the wrong order, CloudFront drops the TCP connection, returns HTTP error code 502, and sets the `X-Cache` header to `Error from cloudfront`."* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot as i have specified i am using aws ssl certificate, doesn't cloudfront recognize this as trusted certificate? do i need to take any extra steps so that cloudfront take it as trusted certificate.

Comment: You cert is probably deployed correctly on Cloudfront.  The problem is that cloudfront can't talk to your server securely.

Comment: @user15460 your server has an SSL certificate on it that claims it was issued to `www.example.com` (not an example value, this is what the certificate actually says) -- in other words, it is a placeholder certificate for testing purposes only.  You can't use this certificate on your origin server with CloudFront, because CloudFront correctly considers it untrustworthy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot now i have set up elb and its working fine but sub domains files such as css or js files are not served on ssl and thus blocked by browser.Also subdomain pages such as example.com/about are not being redirected to ssl version. how can i fix it?